# How can I manipulate just part of a Perl string?

Tags: regex, perl, mediawiki

I'm trying to write some Perl to convert some HTML-based text over to MediaWiki format and hit the following problem: I want to search and replace within a delimited subsection of some text and wondered if anyone knew of a neat way to do it. My input stream is something like:

```
Please mail <a href="mailto:help@myco.com&amp;Subject=Please help&amp;Body=Please can some one help me out here">support.</a> if you want some help.
```

and I want to change `Please help` and `Please can some one help me out here` to `Please%20help` and `Please%20can%20some%20one%20help%20me%20out%20here` respectively, without changing any of the other spaces on the line.

Naturally, I also need to be able to cope with more than one such link on a line so splicing isn't such a good option.

I've taken a good look round Perl tutorial sites (it's not my first language) but didn't come across anything like this as an example. Can anyone advise an elegant way of doing this?

Comment: From the subject I thought that the answer was going to be "Use `substr()` as an lvalue." It's nice to see an X/Y question that actually tells you what Y is.

Comment: I couldn't think of a better subject line right off so I just matched the original one in intent.

Comment: @brian d foy: Out of interest, what was wrong with the original subject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your task has two parts. Find and replace the `mailto` URIs - use a HTML parsing module for that. This topic is covered thoroughly on Stack Overflow.

The other part is to canonicalise the URI. The module [`URI`](http://p3rl.org/URI) is suitable for this purpose.

```
use URI::mailto;
my @hrefs = ('mailto:help@myco.com&amp;Subject=Please help&amp;Body=Please can some one help me out here');
print URI::mailto->new($_)->as_string for @hrefs;
__END__
mailto:help@myco.com&amp;Subject=Please%20help&amp;Body=Please%20can%20some%20one%20help%20me%20out%20here
```

Comment: Ah, I thought you might say something like that. I was hoping it might be a nice simple one liner in Perl! What I didn't make clear was that the input is actually very old TWiki with embedded HTML tags. I'm not sure what an HTML parser would make of it but I'm going to give it, and the canonicalisation, a try. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score -3):

Why dont you just search for the "Body=" tag until the quotes and replace every space with %20.

I would not even use regular expresions for that since I dont find them useful for anything except mass changes where everything on the line is changes.

A simple loop might be the best solution.

Comment: If you "dont find them useful for anything except mass changes where everything on the line is changes," then I suggest you should learn about more nuanced uses of them to take advantage of their power.